# How is this possible? Things should get printed but they dont

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine, postman

I don't understand how the console.logs not getting printed.

```
import { GenericRepository, getGenericRepository } from '../src/database/repository/GenericRepository';
import { start, stop } from '../src/index';
import request from 'request';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3200/';

const getTable = async (tableName: string) => {
  const data = {
    'tableName': 'tableName'
  };

  const header = {
    url: baseUrl + 'table',
    method: 'POST',
    json: true
  };

  console.log('hello');
  request.post({
    url: 'http://localhost:3200/getTable',
    body: data,
    json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log('getting angry');
    if (error) {
      console.error('error: ', error);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post({
      url: 'http://localhost:3200/getTable',
      json: data
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      console.log('getting angry');
      if (error) {
        console.error('error: ', error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        resolve('response' + response);
      }
    });
  })


}

describe('A suite', function () {
  beforeAll(async done => {
    // await start()f.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
    done();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    console.log('afterall')
  });

  it('contains spec with an expectation', async done => {
    console.log('spec executed')

    getTable('supply').then(result => {
      console.log('result: ', result)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });


    console.log('after getTable')

    done();
    // expect(table.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

Neither of these are getting printed:

```
 console.log('getting angry');
 console.error('error: ', error);
 console.log(response);
 console.log('result: ', result);
 console.log('result: ', result);
 console.log(response);
```

what actually gets printed is:
Started
spec executed
hello
after getTable
.afterall

Please help me understand what's going on!.
I tested it with postman the server is working properly.
I would expect that the request would return the same result as the postman does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it('contains spec with an expectation', async done => {
  console.log('spec executed')

  getTable('supply').then(result => {
    console.log('result: ', result)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
  });

  console.log('after getTable')

  done();
  // expect(table.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

This code says to synchronously do all of the following: Call getTable, which returns a promise. Then schedule some stuff to be done when (if) that promise resolves. Then call done(), thus ending the test. Since the test has been ended, the async stuff in getTable doesn't happen, nor do the `.then` callbacks.

Instead, you need to wait until getTable's promise is done resolving before you finish the test. Also, since you're already in an async function, you don't need to be using `.then` callbacks, and don't need to use `done()` since jasmine knows to wait until the async function's promise finishes. For example:

```
it('contains spec with an expectation', async () => {
  console.log('spec executed')

  try {
    const result = await getTable('supply')
    console.log('result: ', result)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }

  console.log('after getTable')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but your call to `done()` is not in the right place. The test will run, launch the `Promise` and then immediately notify that it is `done()` before the promise has chance to resolve or reject.

Try moving the `done()` to within the `then` and `catch` blocks:

```
it('contains spec with an expectation', async done => {

  getTable('supply').then(result => {
    console.log('result: ', result)
    done()
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error)
    done.fail(error)
  });
});
```

Comment: Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms. Any idea how to solve this? Whats wrong with the request call. With postman I get the result with the same json data and same uri,

Comment: nvm I reworte everything and now works, thank you for you help! If could I would accept your answer as well.